# Using Jquery, can I prevent landscape mode in a mobile browser?

Tags: jquery

I have a website, it is really responsive however for landscape mobile it is becoming very unresponsive. I have been on sites where it is not possible to view the website landscape. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Screen Orientation API ([spec](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Orientation_API)) provides a means of locking the screen orientation using a [`lock` method](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#lock-method-lock-screen-to-a-specific-orientation) and passing in an [orientation type](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#dom-orientationlocktype), e.g.:

```
screen.orientation.lock("portrait");
```

Note that this is currently an experimental technology.